# Microsoft Access - SQL-generated field evaluated as Text instead of Single data type

Tags: sql, ms-access, types, latitude-longitude

I have a SQL statement (saved as "LocationSearch" in Access) that calculates distance between two points and returns the "Distance" as a generated field.

```
SELECT Int((3963*(Atn(-(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
    Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
    Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))/Sqr(-(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
    Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
    Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))*(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
    Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
    Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))+1))+2*Atn(1)))*10)/10 AS Distance, *
FROM Locations
ORDER BY (3963*(Atn(-(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
    Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
    Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))/Sqr(-(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
    Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
    Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))*(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
    Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
    Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))+1))+2*Atn(1)));
```

All the nasty math code you see is what calculates the distance (in miles) in the SQL statement using Latitude and Longitude coordinates.

However, the problem is that the Distance field that is generated by the SQL statement seems to be returned as a string.  If I then add SQL code that asks for locations between a distance of 0 and 45 miles, it returns ANY Distance value that starts between "0" and "45".  This includes a location with a distance of "1017" miles.  Apparently, the Distance field is a text field, not a number field.  So I can't use the "BETWEEN" statement.  I also can't evaluate using "<" and ">" because it has the same problem.

I saved the SQL query above as a saved query called "LocationSearch".  This way I can run secondary queries against it, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LocationSearch WHERE Distance < @MaxDistance
```

Access will ask for the @lat, @long and @MaxDistance parameters, then the locations will be returned in a recordset, ordered by distance.  However, the problem that occurs is when I enter a MaxDistance of 45.  With a table containing locations on the West Coast of the US, and a @lat of 47 and a @long of -122 (near Seattle), Access returns the following:

[image]

Notice also that the "Distance" field is right-formatted so it appears to be a numeric field, yet for some reason the query returns a location in San Diego, which is 1,017 miles away.  My guess is that it was evaluating the Distance field as a text field, and in an ASCII comparison, I believe that "1017" lies between "0" and "45".

One other thing:  I'm using ASP 3.0 (classic) to access this query using JET OLEDB 4.0.

Anyone know how to define the Distance field as a number?

Thanks!

**--- EDIT ---**

Using HansUp's idea from his answer below, I tried this query to force Access to consider the Distance field as a Single precision number:

```
SELECT * FROM LocationSearch WHERE CSng(Distance) < @MaxDistance
```

Even this returned the exact same results as before which included the location in San Diego, 1017 miles away.

Comment: my advice: leave the imperial, and go to metric!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find a way to return numerical values instead of text from that `Duration` field expression, use your query as a subquery, then cast `Duration` in the containing query.

```
SELECT CSng(sub.Duration) AS Duration_as_single
FROM
    (
        -- your existing query --
    ) AS sub
WHERE CSng(sub.Duration) BETWEEN 0 AND 45
ORDER BY 1;
```

That approach also makes for a nicer `ORDER BY` ... if that counts for anything.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your query without the `select *`, and without the `FROM` and `ORDER BY` clauses.
I added in an extra column into the `SELECT` to prove that strings return as left-justified in access's grid.

```
SELECT Int((3963*(Atn(-(
Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))/Sqr(-(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))*(Sin(LATITUDE/57.2958)*
Sin([@lat]/57.2958)+Cos(LATITUDE/57.2958)*Cos([@lat]/57.2958)*
Cos([@lng]/57.2958-LONGITUDE/57.2958))+1))+2*Atn(1)))*10)/10 AS Distance, 
'test' as test
```

I was prompted for four parameters, but in the end, I got back a two-column table:

[image]

Since the first column in right-justified, and the second (clearly a string) is left-justified, it appears that access is indeed returning it as a numeric for me. This was in Access 2010.

--**EDIT**--

I just created a new two-column table called `Locations`. It has a field `id` (autonumber) and a field `Field1` (text). I ran the original query provided by OP and it works fine (distance is returned as a number).

This leads to wonder... Does the OP's `Locations` table have it's own Distance field, that is a string? Otherwise, the problem has got to be in the code calling the SQL statement, not in the statement or the jet engine itself.

Comment: Another way to illustrate the data type is to give that field expression to `TypeName()`

Comment: @HansUp HUGE +1 for that. FWIW, passing the result into `TypeName()` returned `Double`.

Comment: Good, that seems to me like what *should* happen.  I can't figure out why OP gets text instead.

Comment: Likewise, it's got me stumped. I just added the `FROM` expression back in, and it still works fine.

Comment: @HansUp Updated my answer with more results and my conclusion.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling, the Locations table doesn't have a Distance field.  It just contains some basic information about each location, including the Latitude and Longitude which are used in the query.  I'm going to edit the question above to include some extra details.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, solved it!

HansUp, your idea turned out to be the solution.  I tried adding the `CSng()` function on the `@MaxDistance` parameter in the SQL query and that was what fixed it.

Here's the modified secondary SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM LocationSearch WHERE CSng(Distance) < CSng(@MaxDistance)
```

Thanks for your help, everybody!  You all rock.

Happy New Year.